# mongo cluster connection issue with Sidekiq + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, sidekiq, mongoid5

I am using rails - 6.0.3, mongoid - 7.0.13 along with using mongo atlas cloud
**mongo cluster connection with rails application is working fine** but with sidekiq job we are getting

exception -
**ArgumentError: Host 'mongodb+srv://********:*********@mongo_url****/my_database?retryWrites=true&w=majority' should not contain protocol. Did you mean to not use an array?**

**ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Host 'mongodb+srv://********:*********@mongo_url****/my_database?retryWrites=true&w=majority' should not contain protocol. Did you mean to not use an array?**

I am passing mongo cloud connection url in ENV[MONGO_URL]

Any help is really appreciated

I have verified same Mongo cluster version with same setup working fine with Production setup
I also tested after increasing database connection pool size but no luck.